# Material Icons are not loading in flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

When I try to add material icon with underscore in it ex. Icons.water_drop its not loading but if i added Icons.water its normally load

tried alot of solutions like checking the pubspec.yaml   uses-material-design: true , making new clean project , flutter clean and nothing happens

E/ion     (27469): ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument

The code below is not the shown in the picture but have the same issue

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Icon(Icons.water_drop),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[First Image showing that Icons.water is normally appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y6qm.png)

[Second one showing that Icons.water_drop not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhaTB.png)

Comment: try to did `flutter clean` and try to did `flutter pub get` after flutter clean

Comment: i've tried this as well

Comment: did you try using custom icon already?, this one might be helped. but you need to download it from some website

Comment: Are you importing material or Cupertino packages?

Comment: yes sure `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`

Comment: or try to add `const` infront of your ListTile

Comment: same issue didn't work

Comment: which version of the flutter channel are you? you may be on a channel where that might be outdated. Try also doing a flutter upgrade (if you're ready to, of course!)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code not as an image but as text

Comment: @MendelG i've added the code

Comment: @RomanJaquez im trying this one thanks

Comment: @RomanJaquez thanks it worked doing flutter upgrade which is weird cause the version i used was not outdated

Comment: That was interesting. Anyway glad it worked out.